# Get values from repeater that is filled with objects from a custom class

Tags: asp.net

I have stuck on how to get values from a specific row in a repeater.

I fill the repeater with objects from a coustom class like this(C#):

```
    rptVisaBarn.DataSource = client.SkickaForalderBarn();
    rptVisaBarn.DataBind();
```

(ASP.NET)

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFornamn" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NamnBarn").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lvlPersonNr" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PersonNrBarn").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
```

The thing i want to is when i click on the button that creates on every row i want to colect values from that object on that row and send them to a method that i have in a webbserivce.

I have tried some things but they dont work and i dont know where i should go from here..

A little help in the right direction would be really nice!

I you need more info just ask, becuse i really need help with this..

Answer (score 0):

Do you want that click to be client or server side?  There's a decent writeup here:  http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3609466/ASPNET-Tip-Responding-to-the-Repeater-Controls-ItemCommand-Event.htm.

The highlights:

Register (somewhere) your repeater item command event.  e.g.:

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnInit(e);
   rptData.ItemCommand += new RepeaterCommandEventHandler(rptData_ItemCommand);
}
```

Create a button in your repeater:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Runat="server" CssClass="tabletext" CommandName="edit" 
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("pkRecordID") %>'>Edit</asp:LinkButton>
```

Handle the event:

```
private void rptData_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Item contains your data item.
    //e.CommandName contains 'edit' in the case, or whatever is in your button's CommandName
    //e.CommandArgument contains a record ID in this case, or whatever is in your button's CommandArgument
}
```

Comment: Can you give a code example how to get the data item, because it seems like i cant find the objects.

Comment: e.Item normally contains your data item.  However, if your binding isn't re-occuring in the post back, than more than likely it'll be blank.  Also, this will NOT provide any "updates" the user may have inputted if you have additional inputs in your repeater.  Normal use case is to simply use the `CommandArgument` and pull data freshly from the database and look at surrounding elements in order to do any necessary manipulation.